# Can I use an ssh key to authenticate an HTTP request?

Tags: authentication, oauth, ssh, rsa

I'm writing a command-line tool that will need to interact with a webservice, and I would like to be able to authenticate it using the user's ssh key. I'm wondering if I can do something like this:

1. The user makes a request to a url (say `/auth/login`), with the user's user id.
2. The server knows the users' ssh public key, and encrypts a session id using that key.
3. The user decrypts the server's response using their private key, and gives that session id with each following request.

I suppose my main question is:  have I just reinvented a well-known security mechanism?  It sounds a bit like oauth, but I'm not really sure if or how it maps into any existing oauth workflow.

Comment: Given your scenario why not just use something more standard like SSL/TLS client authentication? It seems about the same from a user experience point of view as your scheme, but it has almost two decades of scrutiny and improvements from the best security minds.

Comment: Can I use SSL/TLS authentication using an SSH key?

Comment: Yes and no. Why does it have to be an SSH key? Yes, because an RSA key is an RSA key and you can always repackage the SSH public RSA key into an X509 certificate and the ssh private RSA key into a PKCS#12 (.p12) file. No because you probably want to rethink authentication and start from scratch with client certificate enrollment.

Comment: @GregS - Convenience.  Most programmers already have an SSH key in their home directory, right?

Comment: This is a webservice for programmers only?

Comment: so any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

SSH and HTTP(s) are obviously different protocol. You will need multiple requests to different services (with shared session storage). A poor man's solution could leverage a `ssh` tunnel. Within your command-line tool you'd start a process keeping connection to the server

```
          /---- a local port (entry to the tunnel)
         /
ssh -L 8080:localhost:8081 remote.server.com
               \         \-------------------- remote port (publicly not accessible)
                \
                 \--- address resolve at the other end of tunnel (on server)
```

Once the tunnel is established and user authenticated via his public ssh key. The CLI tool can make requests to local http port `8080` which will routed via secure tunnel to the server. The request will be encrypted but the server doesn't know anything about the user nor his ssh key. And we either have to keep the tunnel open or establish new connection for each request to HTTP server (like VPN).

In order to implement this properly, you have to implement/modify ssh server.
Here's basically what you want, a [POC of HTTP authentication via ssh](https://jesse.sh/http-authentication-via-ssh/) and [source code here](https://github.com/jshawl/auths.sh).

The code uses a nice project [charmbracelet/wish](https://github.com/charmbracelet/wish), which implements the ssh server.

```
            /--- port 8080 - HTTP sever
./auths.sh -
            \--- port 4202 - SSH server
```

1. User visits https://auths.sh, server generate random UUID and it tells user to run command `ssh auths.sh 28c21335-6ba1-4d3a-8835-e737811297d5`
2. Use executes ssh command with given UUID, server writes user's public key to a file `/tmp/28c21335-6ba1-4d3a-8835-e737811297d5`
3. Browser is authenticated (UUID stored in cookie `SESSION_ID`), HTTP server knows user's public ssh key.

With the `wish` package you can easily implement custom authentication:

```
s, err := wish.NewServer(
        wish.WithAddress(fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", host, port)),
        wish.WithHostKeyPEM(pem),
        wish.WithPublicKeyAuth(func(ctx ssh.Context, key ssh.PublicKey) bool { 
        // <- validate public key against e.g. authorized_keys
            return true 
        }),
        wish.WithMiddleware(
            sshHandler,
            logging.Middleware(),
        ),
```

You can modify the code and add the the session encryption and decryption.